# How to open file from storage by Provider in Android 8.1

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I want to open and install a apk file from storage, i used code below:

```java
        File fileToOpen = new File(path);
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        if (fileToOpen.exists()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileToOpen);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);
            } else {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileToOpen), type);
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

and in my **manifest** file:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
        </provider>
```

my **provider_path.xml**:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path path="." name="external_files" />
</paths>
```

I have to request permission in runtime and accepted, but after i call this method, nothing happen. File is already existed, what happend in my code? please help me find it, thank so much :((

Answer (score 0):

To request APK for installation,

```
File file = new File("YOUR_FILE_PATH");

Uri uri;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    uri = getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
} else {
    uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
}

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Your manifeast should be,

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="YOUR_PACKAGENAME_HERE.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

And provider_path should be (It will cover almost all of available devices),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add your package name in manifeast.xml. If it still persist, try to change provider_path.xml.

Comment: tks u so much, i will try it

Comment: i have try it, but everything is same and i found a solution, that is add REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGE to the Manifest, it was working